# How can I bring my yticklabels closer to geom_tile?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I've been trying to recreate some heatmaps from [this](https://www.r-bloggers.com/making-faceted-heatmaps-with-ggplot2/), but my y ticks are quite far apart from the remainder of geom_tile.

Here is my code

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggthemes)
library(viridis)



d <-c('Sunday','Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday')
days <- factor(d, levels = d,ordered=TRUE)

L = rnorm(7*24,0,20)

df <- data.frame(days,L) %>%arrange(days)

df['Time'] = c(0:23)

gg <- ggplot(data  = df, aes(x = Time, y = days, fill = L))+
      geom_tile(color = 'white',size = 0.1)+
      scale_fill_viridis('')+
      coord_equal()+
      labs(x = NULL, y = NULL, title = 'Practice HeatMap')+
       theme_tufte(base_family="Helvetica")+
      theme(axis.ticks=element_blank())

print(gg)
```

and the resulting plot

[image]

Even using hjust wont move the labels closer.  How can I achieve a cleaner look?

Comment: perhaps add `scale_x_continuous(expand=c(0,0))` to the ggplot object to take care of the extra margin